# Customizing UIPageViewController gesture recognizers Scroll behavior

Tags: ios, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I want to implement `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` **gesture delegate** in **pageviewcontroller.m** file but i can't get any gesture as:

```
NSArray *temp = self.gestureRecognizers;
NSLog(@"count %i",temp.count); // this logs count 0 

NSArray *temp = self.view.gestureRecognizers;
NSLog(@"count %i",temp.count);  // this also logs count 0 

for (UIGestureRecognizer *gR in temp) {
    gR.delegate = self;
}
```

in above code self is pointing towards pageviewcontroller.

therefore i can't assign delegate to pageviewcontroller gestures.

**Edited Part:**

OK I got it, I am not getting any gesture object because of uipageviewscroll style.

But I have a problem I need to disable pageviewcontroller **pan gesture** and need to scroll the pageviewcontroller from two buttons, like if user try to pan, and it's starting point is inside my uibuttons frame then pageviewcontroller should scroll otherwise not.

I am using transitionStyle **UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll**.

Any solution for this...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying so many hacks, I finally got solution.

What i did, first got the pageviewcontroller scorll view in a property

```
for (UIView *view in mypageviewcontroller.view.subviews) {
  if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
  {
      pagescrollview= (UIScrollView *)view;
  }
}
```

Then assigned pan gesture to pageviewcontroller scorllview and gesture delegate.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* g1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                       action:@selector(gesture)];

[g1 setDelegate:self];

[pagescrollview addGestureRecognizer:g1];
```

Then in gesture delegate , i checked whether the gesture starts from my desire points, if starts from a location that should scroll pageviewcontroller then this delegate method should return no to enable original pagescorllview gesture to receive pan gesture.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber)<=NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
        touchPoint.y -=44;
    else
        touchPoint.y -=64;

    PGNavigationController *nav =ViewControllerArray[VisiblePageindex];
    PageContentVC *pagecontentvc = ((PageContentVC *) nav.visibleViewController);

    if (touchPoint.y > pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.origin.y && (pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.size.height+pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.origin.y )>touchPoint.y && touchPoint.x >pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.origin.x
        && touchPoint.x<(pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.origin.x+pagecontentvc.leftpanalbtn.frame.size.width)) {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (touchPoint.y > pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.origin.y && (pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.size.height+pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.origin.y )>touchPoint.y && touchPoint.x >pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.origin.x
             && touchPoint.x<(pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.origin.x+pagecontentvc.rightpanalbtn.frame.size.width))
    {

        return NO;
    }
    if( touchPoint.y>282 && touchPoint.x>118 &&touchPoint.y<282+75 && touchPoint.x < 118+85)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    // else if()
  }
  return YES;
}
```

hope it help someone else.

Comment: Where is @selector(gesture) and what does it do?